# how to fix this problem TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Please help me i want to finish this tomorrow

```
if (baru.voiceChannelID === channelid) {
  // const Role = baru.guild.roles.get("724997095236304987");
  let Role = baru.member.roles.some((r) => ["IRON", "BRONZE"].includes(r.name));

  baru.guild
    .createChannel(`${Role.name} | ${baru.user.username}`, "voice")
    .then((tempChannel) => {
      tempChannel.overwritePermissions(baru.guild.id, {
        CONNECT: false,
      });

      tempChannel.overwritePermissions(Role.id, {
        CONNECT: true,
      });
      tempChannel.setParent(kategorikanal);
      baru.setVoiceChannel(tempChannel.id);
      tempChannel.setUserLimit("5");
    })

    .catch(console.error);
}
```

This the main of the problem code

Comment: Well what is is `baru`? It looks like you are using it as a `Message` class and a `Guild` class?

Comment: music.on('voiceStateUpdate',(lama, baru) => {
var state = null;

Comment: Looks like the issue is that `baru.member` is undefined, try logging what baru is. Looking at docs its a `VoiceState` which does have a member property, might be that it doesn't have one on leave

Comment: `(oldMember, newMember)` like this?

Comment: No changing the parameter names doesn't do anything, before your if statement add this code: `console.log(baru)`, and add the result to your post

Answer (score 0):

[Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) returns a boolean.

You are going to get an error because there is no name property on the boolean.

```
  baru.guild
    .createChannel(`${Role.name} | ${baru.user.username}`, "voice")
```

also, log the `baru` object to your console so you can check if it has a roles property or not.  It says that it is undefined.

Comment: music.on('voiceStateUpdate',(lama, baru) => {
var state = null;

Answer (score 0):

`baru.member.roles.some`

`baru` doesn't have `.member`, so it can't look for `.roles`

Have you checked if `baru` has the correct data?

Comment: music.on('voiceStateUpdate',(lama, baru) => {
var state = null;

Comment: console.log `baru` and check if it has a `member` property

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using v11, in v11 its a `GuildMember` not a `VoiceState`

So instead of `baru.member` it's just baru, you should probably rename the variables so it makes more sense, for example `oldMember` and `newMember`

So here's the code change:

```js
let Role = baru.member.roles.some((r) => ["IRON", "BRONZE"].includes(r.name));
```

=>

```js
let Role = baru.roles.some((r) => ["IRON", "BRONZE"].includes(r.name));
```

Also you cannot use use the guild id for overwritePermissions, if you are trying to change it for everyone then you need to use `@everyone` .id:

```js
tempChannel.overwritePermissions(baru.guild.id, {
   CONNECT: false,
})
```

=>

```js
tempChannel.overwritePermissions(baru.guild.defaultRole.id, {
   CONNECT: false,
})
```

Comment: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Supplied parameter was neither a User nor a Role`

Comment: That's because you can't put a guild's id for the overwrite permissions, if you are trying to overwrite for everyone you will need to use guild.defaultRole.id, edited my answer.

Comment: That's because `baru.member.roles.some` returns a boolean, not a role. Use `baru.member.roles.find()` instead.

Comment: I just answered why it's undefined, maybe you didn't read it since it was right before your comemnt. Also no, the question has been answered, so either learn some debugging or make seperate posts.

Comment: i got some bug again 

`.createChannel(`${Role.name} | ${baru.user.username}`,"voice")                         ^
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null`